# Problema com Ruby Gem Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-charts

Após a mudança para horário de verão estou encontrando um problema com a **Gem Chartkick**.

Montei minha *query* da seguinte maneira:

```
Ticket.unscoped.where('created_at >= ? ', Time.now - 10.days).group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

O resultado retornado foi:

> {Mon, 20 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>7, Tue, 21 Oct 2014 00:00:00
>   BRST -02:00=>9, Wed, 22 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>6, Thu, 23 Oct
>   2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>5, Fri, 24 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST
>   -02:00=>6, Sat, 25 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>0, Sun, 26 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>0, Mon, 27 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>2,
>   Tue, 28 Oct 2014 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>1}

O gráfico gerado é o seguinte:

[image: Parte do gráfico gerado]

Os dados estão retornando corretamente, o problema me parece que é do gráfico que mesmo recebendo os dados corretos exibe tudo zerado.

Comment: Alguém já teve este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Primeiro use a opção `series: false`; Mais info: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/issues/63

2) O correto é utilizar `Time.zone.now` ao invés de `Time.now`; Mais info: http://rrmartins.com/blog/2012/12/02/traducao-trabalhando-com-time-zones-em-ruby-on-rails/

Ficaria assim:

```
Ticket.unscoped.where('created_at >= ? ', Time.zone.now - 10.days).group_by_day(:created_at, series: false).count
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado.